# Обработка формы на другом сервере

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

Я реализую загрузку файлов на сайте и я хочу что бы все фото хранились на отдельном домене, который может быть даже на отдельном сервере, но не могу сообразить как через ajax отправить всё на другой домен. Я хочу что бы всё файлы хранились на отдельном домене и сервере а пути к этим файлам их типы и наследствия хранились в бд (ни хочу хранить фотки в бд(есть на то причины)) подскажите как реализовать через любимый ПЫХЫПЫ выгрузку файла на другой сервер. Спасибо.

Comment: я себе такое делал через проксирование nginx и просто не затрагивая php и апач на основном проксировал на другой сервер запрос, будь то уже аяксом или просто синхронный не важно. (можно конечно и сразу напрямую отправлять запрос на другой сайт, но тогда все будут видеть url обработчика загрузки, учтите что нужно проверять на сервере откуда пришел запрос, что бы разрешить загрузку только с основного сайта и то с лимитами и жесткими проверками сессий - куки только для сервера и т.д)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же как и на свой, только URL пиши тот который нужен тебе и все

```js
var formData = $("#Myform").serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "https://example.com/", // атрибут `action="..."` из формы.
  cache: false, // запрошенные страницы не будут закешированы браузером.
  data: formData, // data: data - больше ничего тут не надо!
  dataType: 'html', // чтобы jQuery распарсил `success` ответ.
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data.message);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert('Ошибка отправки сообщения');

    var json = error.responseJSON;

    // Обработка ошибок валидации.
    if (422 === error.status) {
      var errors = json.errors;

      for (var error in errors) {
        console.log(error, errors[error][0])
      }
    } else {
      console.log(json.message)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А что с правами доступа? файл на чужом сервере просто так без ошибок примет запрос?

Comment: @DmitryDevelop да

Comment: а как насчёт безопасности? Просто вдруг чужой человек построит аналогичный запрос и пошлёт его на этот же сервер, ведь js и html код всегда можно посмотреть, он просто возьмёт запрос и начнёт его бесконечно посылать, вот и -сервер...

Comment: Делай проверку на то, откуда был отправлен запрос `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` и `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` или делай сессионную переменную которую проверяй на странице скрипта